# Parsing GMT-5 +DST with NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, ios, date

I'm having a hard time converting a date from string to a NSDate from the following format:

```
2012-09-05 12:00 GMT-5 +DST
```

So far I have this code:

```
NSString *myDateStr = @"2012-09-05 12:00 GMT-5 +DST";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:myDateStr];
```

I don't have any control over the format of the date string since it comes from an API.

Will I need to write a custom formatter for parsing this perhaps?

Comment: if you have solved your query.. using my solution.. please accept

Answer (score 0):

Pass your date string to this function, which would return NSDate object.

You can recheck if you are getting the correct value as **GMT-5 +DST is same as CDT**. [Reference](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/usa/central-time/central-daylight-time.htm)

Setting the timeZone as CDT would give you the same result.

```
-(NSDate *)timeConvert:(NSString *)string
{
      NSString *firstString = [string substringToIndex:16];
      NSString *lastString = [string substringFromIndex:17];

      NSLog(@"%@, %@", firstString, lastString);
      NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone  timeZoneWithName:lastString];
      NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
      [formatter setTimeZone: timeZone];

      NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:firstString];

      return date;
}
```